# How to avoid creation of zero byte files upon closing a python file in 'w' mode due to an error?

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.4

I'm using Python 3.4.1 64bit on Windows 7. It shouldn't matter to the question at hand, AFAICS, but I've included the information just in case. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
def download_and_save(URL_list, filenames, download_dir):
# Process lists
for URL, filename in zip(URL_list, filenames):
    # Generate full path name
    file_path = download_dir + filename
    # Open a local file.
    with open(file_path, 'w') as local_file:
        # Write whatever is at the URL
        try:
            local_file.write(urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read())
        except urllib.request.URLError as e:
            if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
                print ("We failed to reach the server...")
                print(e.reason)
            elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
                print("The server couldn\'t fullfill the request...")
                print("Error code: ", e.code)
```

When I run this piece of code, I ran into a bunch of errors (getaddrinfo failed - because of a typo). When I checked the directory where this is saved after, I found a bunch of files with the expected file names but zero bytes in length. This makes sense since no writing happened.

I'm trying to figure out why the assumption in this case is to do a touch and create the file anyway rather than not do so. Even more importantly, can I turn off this touch behaviour so that no files are created on close? Am I missing a better way to do this that would completely bypass the problem?

Comment: `with open(file_path, 'w') as local_file` you are creating the files whether  you write to them or not. `w` creates a file if it does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `open` function creates the file. If you don't want the possibility of creating empty files in case of error, create the file after getting the response from the server:

```
try:
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()
    with open(file_path, 'w') as local_file:
        local_file.write(data)
except urllib.request.URLError as e:
    # ... exception handling
```

Comment: Thank you! I have the urge to introduce my palm to my face after reading this. Should've been obvious, but I missed it for some reason. Do you think I should delete the question to preserve a good Signal to Noise ration on the site? It is a pretty dumb one.

Comment: This question is fine and you've got at least one upvote already. :)

Comment: :) I'll accept your answer as soon as the ten minutes pass. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can take two approaches.

1. Delete the file when your code enters in the except block, it means there is an error and you don't want the zero sized file.
2. Use a string to store the value from url read. Only write the string into the file when the url read is successful. This one is the better approach.

Comment: Right. I should have figured out approach two myself, lol. I didn't want to delete the file (bit weird), but it is a perfectly valid solution.

Comment: Yes, approach 2 is the way to go.